# How to run standalone Hibernate 4 SchemaExport with Java Spring config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, schemaexport

We have a Java Spring project using JPA with Hibernate 4 for ORM. We exclusively use Java config, so we don't have any hibernate.properties or persistence.xml mapping files.

We're also using Spring's Jsr310JpaConverters and some custom attribute converters implementing `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter`. The custom converters are picked up automatically by the package scan.

Other than that, our setup is fairly standard, basically just

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = BasePackageMarker.class, repositoryBaseClass = InternalRepositoryImpl.class)
public class JpaConfig {

    // values loaded from property file

    public Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
        jpaProperties.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, getHbm2ddlAuto());
        // ...
        return jpaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setJdbcUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        // ...
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(
                BasePackageMarker.class.getPackage().getName(),
                Jsr310JpaConverters.class.getPackage().getName()
        );
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'm looking for a way to run Hibernate's SchemaExport to create our database schema, without running Tomcat or the Spring application, with the same configuration as starting the application with `hbm2ddl=create`, specifically finding all entity classes and attribute converters. I'd like to run it with Maven, but I can figure that part out once I know where to start.

I've found many outdated answers and libraries for Hibernate 3 or for XML config, nothing seems to work for our setup. I'm sure the answer is already out there, but at this point I'm quite confused and don't know what to try. Any solutions or pointers?

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/jpdigital/hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin is what you are searching for

Comment: You can call something while building - like that maven plugin, or something for gradle. However we are using flyway, some other projects liquibase. That is separate tool / solution which allows versioning, rolling your schema to right version - every deployment.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata thank you, I will take a look. We're using hibernate 4, but that user also has a hibernate4-ddl-maven-plugin on Github, maybe that works.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski We're using Liquibase too. In fact, part of the reason why I'm asking for this, is to create a Liquibase diff between schemas of different revisions/branches.

Comment: @DarioSeidl - in that case I would create dedicated task in your build system...

Comment: The hibernate4-ddl-maven-plugin works basically, but doesn't pick up the attribute converters, e.g. `LocalDateTime` fields become `tinyblob` instead of `Date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need go with AnnotationConfiguration(): 
In hibernate, database connection can also be achieved without using hibernate.cfg.xml. In hibernate annotation, there is a class named as AnnotationConfiguration. AnnotationConfiguration provides the method to configure database properties. 
There are different methods of AnnotationConfiguration like .addAnnotatedClass, .addProperties etc. There is .configure() methods which seeks hibernate.cfg, We need not to use .configure() if we are not intended to use hibernate.cfg.

suppose I have entity User

```
package com.persistence;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")  
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil class

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory concreteSessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            Properties prop= new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate");
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
            prop.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            prop.setProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

            concreteSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
           .addPackage("com.persistence")
                   .addProperties(prop)
                   .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                   .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static Session getSession()
            throws HibernateException {
        return concreteSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        Session session=getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user=(User)session.get(User.class, new Integer(1));
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        session.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me the right idea. I just need to call  `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter` to register our converters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution based on Bhushan Uniyal's answer. Using reflection to find our entities and attribute converters.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "user");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "xxxx");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
            .addPackage("com.persistence")
            .addProperties(prop);

    Reflections basePackageReflections = new Reflections(BasePackageMarker.class.getPackage().getName());

    for (Class<?> entityClass : basePackageReflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class)) {
        System.out.println("Adding entity class: " + entityClass.getSimpleName());
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(entityClass);
    }

    for (Class<? extends AttributeConverter> attributeConverter : basePackageReflections.getSubTypesOf(AttributeConverter.class)) {
        System.out.println("Adding attribute converter: " + attributeConverter.getSimpleName());
        cfg.addAttributeConverter(attributeConverter);
    }

    cfg.addAttributeConverter(Jsr310JpaConverters.LocalDateConverter.class);
    cfg.addAttributeConverter(Jsr310JpaConverters.LocalDateTimeConverter.class);
    cfg.addAttributeConverter(Jsr310JpaConverters.LocalTimeConverter.class);
    cfg.addAttributeConverter(Jsr310JpaConverters.InstantConverter.class);

    new SchemaExport(cfg).create(true, true);
}
```